# Bot se para en un cierto tiempo Discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js

tengo un bot de discord que hace que tengas que escribir una palabra para asi mostrarte los canales de discord, es como una verificacion que eres humano, el problema es que el bot se detiene y hay que volverlo a correr y pues no se que hacer aqui dejo una imagen y el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const mySecret = process.env['token']


client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Estoy listo!");
 });
 
 client.on("message", (message) => {
   if(message.content.startsWith("ping")) {
     message.channel.send("pong!");
   }
 });

client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.channel.id === "494730342289244182"){
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.content === 'Acepto'){
      message.member.roles.add("957188846100045835");
      message.author.send("Gracias por verificarte ¡Bienvenido a Ark4Fun!");
      message.delete();
    }
    else{
      message.author.send("¿Tienes inconvenientes? Envía un mensaje personal al Administrador o abre un Ticket al soporte");
      message.delete();
    }
  }
});
 
 client.login(mySecret);
```

el bot se esta corriendo en https://replit.com/

Comment: No acabo de entender el problema: ¿funciona durante un tiempo y luego se para?

Comment: si, el bot corre pero pasa un tiempo y se detiene, no es constante entonces, debo darle run de nuevo

Comment: Creo que es la política de `replit` para cuentas gratuitas, muy parecido a Heroku.